# Error in Installing Magento 2.0

Tags: php, magento-2.0

I am new to Magento. I have installed Magento on localhost and I am using XAMPP (Windows) server. The installation was successful.

And when I opened the home page, it was so blank with no images on it

**Store home page:**
[image]

When I opened the console I got the following errors

**Console errors:**
[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common problem on windows servers (mostly local xampp servers) because these servers dont have symlinks.

Do this to fix it:

1. go to app/etc/di.xml and delete name="view_preprocessed" in virtualType name="developerMaterialization" section.
2. go to pub/static and delete all files except the .htaccess

after that I installed it again and it worked

Comment: HI thank you so much  the installation was successful without any errors.but the home page was same as the previous installation with LUMA logo.Is this the successful installation or there will any default theme will be there upon installation.and also i cannot able to access     the admin panel ,i am getting the below error  This webpage has a redirect loop
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Yes the luma logo is correct, that means something in your code redirects to itself like an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Install composer. You can use Composer to install Magento 2. It is a tool for dependent management in PHP which allows you to declare the dependent libraries your project needs and install them for you. Composer enables you to manage Magento 2, extensions, and their dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions of the /pub/media and pub/static folders

[system permissions for Magento 2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/file-system-perms.html)